# Who creates malicious Tor nodes, why, and how to they work?

Tags: circuit, node, vulnerability, threats

I understand the concept of a malicious Tor node, but am confused on a few things.

- Who makes malicious Tor nodes? I assume non-Tor friendly governments and non-government threat actors.
- Why would they do this, and how does it benefit them?
- What makes a Tor node malicious and what are some of the bad things that can happen from ending up with one in your circuit?

Comment: This is a good question, but very broad. You might be interested in reading about a recent example of malicious nodes: https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-relays/2020-October/019045.html

Comment: Thank you, this is quite helpful. So it seems like the culprits of the attacks are not government related but individual rouge threat actors; given that they seem to be related to cryptocurrency theft / pwning. It's very troubling to know that there is not a threat using the Tor network, but worse; attacking Tor itself. Even more troubling to know even Tor cannot be untouched by the COVID-19 pandemic. However, thanks to the volunteer based nature of Tor it's good to know there are things all of us average users can do to help:
 - Donate to the project
 - Host a node